# Magento product details page add multi select checkbox filter

Tags: product, attributes, filter

I want to add a multi select check box filter to my product details page.

1: I created an attribute (multi select attibute)
2: Marked category as anchor

Now I can see filter as a link. I want multi select checkbox there. How can it be done. Is there any setting in admin for that ?

sample url : http://goo.gl/TKf9uQ

See color filter there , I want multi select there .

Comment: What is your magento version ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many extensions available that will give you this functionality. Some of them are as below,

1. https://www.fmeaddons.com/magento/free-ajax-layered-navigation-extension.html
2. https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multiple-select-in-layered-navigation-filters.html
3. http://amasty.com/improved-navigation.html
4. http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_layered_navigation_pro.html
5. http://www.manadev.com/seo-layered-navigation-plus

If you wish to develop it yourself you can take guidance from the first two extensions which are free.